# CSS3 transorm rectangle to trapezoid

Tags: css, math, matrix, transformation

I have  a 100x5 div:

[image: From]

and I need to tranform it into a 30px high symmetric trapezoid with 45° angles (see below) using either `matrix3d()` or `rotateX()` and `perspective`. The angles should be exactly 45°

[image: To]

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: I don't know what parameters I should use

Comment: Why don't you try create something? That's the best way to get anything done

Comment: I did and it worked, but PhistucK's answer was better, because the trapezoid's bottom is not bigger than the rectangle's. But I'm still interested, what could the mathematically perfect answer be

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work in Chrome -

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(24px) rotateX(39deg) scale(0.6, 6.4);
transform: perspective(24px) rotateX(39deg) scale(0.6, 6.4);
```

My starting point was [this](http://lea.verou.me/2013/10/slanted-tabs-with-css-3d-transforms/) post, though.